# Get access token from google oauth from code

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

i used following code to get the access token from code as below

```
String code = HttpContext.Current.Request["code"];
                    string redirecturl = HttpContext.Current.Request["url"];                                  

                    string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
                    string grant_type = "authorization_code";
                    string redirect_uri_encode = UrlEncodeForGoogle(url);
                    string data = "code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type={4}&access_type={5}";

                    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
                    string result = null;
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.KeepAlive = true;
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    string param = string.Format(data, code,configurationInfo.oauthclientid , configurationInfo.oauthclientsecretid, redirect_uri_encode, grant_type, "offline");

                    var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
                    using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
                    }

                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        sr.Close();

                    }
```

i am getting response as

```
 The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

i do not know where i went wrong

waiting for your valuable comments

Comment: Have you fixed the problem already?

Comment: @cherhan ya if we give all registration details correctly den it will works

Comment: yup I have a similar piece of code as yours too, good to hear that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Google also provides a higher level library for accessing its services. I find it makes it much easier to work with its APIs.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/